# How can I mentally calculate $\cos(x), x∈(0.7, 1.2)$

Tags: trigonometry, mental-arithmetic

I'm trying to learn how to calculate trig functions in my head. I'm planning on learning $\cos(x), x∈[0,π/2]$ and then using symmetry to calculate the others.

I think the quadratic Maclaurin series at $0$ and the linear at $π/2$ could be calculated in a matter of seconds with some practice. However, I'm struggling to find something that works to 2 D.P. on the interval $(0.7, 1.2)$.

My best idea so far is to use $\color{green}{ 1.3-x/1.3}$, but that is neither fast nor accurate to 2 D.P.

#### Graph of $\color{red}{\cos(x)},\ \ \color{blue}{1-x^2/2},\ \ \color{green}{1.3-x/1.3},\ \ \color{blue}{π/2-x}$:

[image: graph of: cos(x), 1-x^2/2, π/2-x, 1.3-x/1.3]

#### Error:

[image: graph of the error of the above functions]

How can I quickly approximate $\cos(x)$ for $x∈(0.7, 1.2)$? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: A different direction would be to use CORDIC algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC

Comment: Good luck with this. This would be a pretty cool skill to have!

Comment: If you just want quick off-the-cuff estimates within around 10% error, just memorizing landmarks at every 10 degrees has worked quite well for me, for angles above 20 degrees. I suspect it's probably a much rougher estimate than what you're looking for, but I've found it useful for getting a ballpark and doing quick sanity checks. For angles less than 20 degrees, memorize cos(15-degrees) as well, and for angles less than 10 degrees, go with 0.02 times the angle (twice the angle over 100), or better 0.018 times the angle (subtract one tenth of previous answer from itself).

Comment: Why do you want to do this?